# Visual Studio Code Terminal System Limit Problem When Running React App

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am running my react app in Visual Studio Code Terminal. After a few seconds from starting development server, it is throw this error:

```
Error from chokidar (/home/emre/Projects/reactapp/src/components): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/emre/Projects/reactapp/src/components/Counter.js'
```

(This error repeats many in logs.)

But when i run from another terminal, i am running successfully.

How can i increase the system limit?

Note: I am using Linux mint 20.

Comment: Maybe this will help. https://dev.to/shajahan/enospc-system-limit-for-number-of-file-watchers-reached-ubuntu-emberjs-5347

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, with decreasing the system limit.

https://dev.to/shajahan/enospc-system-limit-for-number-of-file-watchers-reached-ubuntu-emberjs-5347